# Converting java files to an executable file for a 1st timer

Tags: java, jar, exe

I have seen other posts about this but I honestly don't know what to do with that information. Can someone explain to me what exactly I need to do please?

I'm using JCreator

Comment: You mean compile a .java file to .class file?  As descirbed in [Compiling & Running a Simple Program](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/compile-136656.html)?

Comment: Are you trying to produce something you can double-click to run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With JCreator you can follow the below process.

1. Click on Configure/Options.
2. Click on Tools in the left column.
3. Click New, and choose Create Jar file.
4. Click on the newly created entry Create Jar File in the left column under Tools.
5. Edit the middle line labeled Arguments: it should have

   cvfm $[PrjName].jar manifest.txt *.class
6. Click OK.

For more information you can refer [this article](http://www.skylit.com/javamethods/faqs/createjar.html)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using eclipse: Right Click on your project->Export:
Export it as an executable JAR. That will allow you to run your program directly from that jar file.

Answer (score 0):

It really comes down to what IDE your using, some have that ability, directly under the menu "file" or "project", where you can them select "export as". Some IDEs however, do not have that ability and only allow you to export as a jar file. If that's the case, you need a third party software to do that for you.

An IDE is the platform you are using to debug your code.